# first type and child

Tags: css, css-selectors

I start to be confused by the `>`, `:nth-child()` and `:nth-of-type()`.

I have :

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <div class="first-img">
        <img />
    </div>
    <div class="first-box">
        <blockquote></blockquote>
    </div>
    <blockquote></blockquote>
</div>
```

I would like to style the first `blockquote` which is DIRECTLY in the `.entry-content` (it means that this is the second `blockquote` in the example) BUT NOT the first `blockquote` which is in the div `.first-box`.

I tried `.entry-content > blockquote:nth-child(2)`, also `.entry-content:nth-of-type(2)`, they do not work.

Does the `.entry-content > blockquote` mean that :

- I choose the blockquotes which are ONLY directly in the entry-content,
  or
- ALL blockquotes which are directly in the entry-content (not in further divs) AND also those who are in divs ?

Comment: You tried the first two; did you try the third? Should answer your question.

Comment: @BoltClock - it is answered and accepted already... thanks !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The selector that you actually need to use is:

```
.entry-content > blockquote:nth-of-type(1) {
  /* styles */
}
```

All the `:nth-*`, `*-child` selectors work only on elements who share a common parent. In the HTML that is provided in the question, the `blockquote` that is directly under the `.entry-content` is the first of its type and so you should use `nth-of-type(1)` to select it instead of `nth-of-type(2)`.

```css
.entry-content > blockquote:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-content">
  <div class="first-img">
    <img />
  </div>
  <div class="first-box">
    <blockquote>Descendant</blockquote>
  </div>
  <blockquote>Child</blockquote>
</div>
```

---

Now for explanations on the other selectors (that either didn't work or weren't tried):

- `.entry-content > blockquote:nth-child(2)` - This will select the `blockquote` that is present directly under an element with `class='entry-content'` if it also happens to be the second child. Here there are two `div` child elements before the `blockquote` and so the `blockquote` is `nth-child(3)`.
- `.entry-content > blockquote:nth-of-type(2)` - There is only one element of type `blockquote` that is directly under the element with `class='entry-content'` and hence this selects nothing.
- `.entry-content > blockquote` - This would select all `blockquote` elements that are directly present under an element with `class='entry-content'` and so would not select the one that is present under the element with `class='first-box`. This is because `>` is child selector and selects only elements that are present directly under the reference element.
- `.entry-content blockquote` - This is very similar to the above one but since `>` is missing it actually selects all `blockquote` elements which are a descendant of an element with `class='entry-content` and so it would select both the `blockquote` elements that are present in the HTML provided in question.
- `.entry-content:nth-of-type(2)` - This one that's provided in the question is a different selector compared to all others. This selects the second element of every type (under a common parent) if it also has `class='.entry-content`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly, thanks for explanations too !

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <div class="first-img">
        <img />
    </div>
    <div class="first-box">
        <blockquote></blockquote>
    </div>
    <blockquote></blockquote>
    <p>
        <blockquote></blockquote>
    </p>
    <blockquote></blockquote>
</div>
```

`.entry-content > blockquote` will select only first level blockquotes. In my example those are `<blockquote>` before and after `<p>`.

`.entry-content blockquote` will select EVERY `<blockquote>`

Comment: Thanks ! Your answer was not complete for my questions, answered only for my second question but thanks for the explanation, i voted for it !

Answer (score 0):

`nth-child()` starts from 0, meaning for example if you have a html code:

```
<div id="main">
     <div>text1</div>
     <div>text2</div>
</div>
```

The CSS selector `#main > div:nth-child(0)` will select the div where "text1" is.
The CSS selector `#main > div:nth-child(1)` will select the div where "text" is: